# Sorting list of list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of list in java where all the elements are string like below,

```
     [livelongandprosper, 2, 1]
     [deals, 11, 1]
     [SEO, 5, 1]
     [Bible, 8, 1]
     [EarnHistory, 2, 1]
     [God, 2, 0]
     [inktober2017, 3, 0]
     [Brand, 22, 1]
     [CoreyFedman, 1, 1]
     [HappyHalloween, 5, 0]
     [innisfree, 1, 1]
     [WorldSeries, 3, 1]
     [Scocco, 1, 1]
```

How can I sort the values of the above list of list on the basis of values in second column and in descending order?

Comment: Collections.sort(lss, new Comparator<List<List<String>>>(){
  public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2)
  {
    //Simple string comparison here, add more sophisticated logic if needed.
    return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
  }
});   This is not working

Comment: Can you actually write Java? Because this sounds as if you'd be better off learning some language basics before trying those tasks

Answer (score -1):

Use a [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), or implement [comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) on the type which populates the list.  And then use [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-);

Comment: Added the comparator code which is not working